# Facebook API Load Time is Twice as Long with User Session

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When the user is the not logged in, my app makes the API calls using the app access token. When the user is logged on then my app makes the API calls using the user access token, but then the pages takes 5-10 seconds longer to load than when the user is not logged in. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: This sounds to me more like a sort of bug report than a programming question... You might be better off posting this on Facebook's [bug system](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)

Comment: I don't think it's a bug because when I test the calls in facebook API explorer for each app token and user token, the response times are about the same.

Comment: That's what I'm saying - if the only difference is what token you use, and one is taking much longer than the other then it might be a problem (or known issue) on Facebook's side.

Comment: No what I'm saying is its not the tokens because the response times are the same when I test the different tokens in API Explorer.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be something to do when authenticating user session, but I'm not sure because I wasn't the one who coded it